# QFtp hasPendingCommands() returns true, but never emits commandStarted(int) signal

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to write a piece of code to connect to a FTP server using c++ with Qt, and I am seeing some strange results. The code is as follows

```
void eos::WeatherRadar::connectToServer()
{
    m_bomServer = new QFtp;
    connect( m_bomServer, SIGNAL( commandStarted( int ) ), this, SLOT( serverConnectStarted() ) );
    connect( m_bomServer, SIGNAL( commandFinished( int, bool ) ), this, SLOT( serverConnectFinished() ) );

    m_bomServer->connectToHost("ftp.bom.gov.au");
    m_bomServer->connectToHost("ftp.bom.gov.au");

    if ( m_bomServer->hasPendingCommands() )
        std::cout << "I have commands to execute..." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "I have no commands even though you just gave me one... WTF!!!" << std::endl;
}
```

Now let the wierdness begin... Notice I have repeated the `connectToHost` line. For some reason, if I only make that call once it says "I have no commands even though you just gave me one... WTF!!!" It is only when I make that call twice that `hasPendingCommands()` returns `true`. Furthermore, whether I make this call once or twice, the `commandStarted(int)` signal is never emitted.

Does anybody have any idea why this would be happening or how to fix it? Thanks in advance guys :-).

Comment: So some further debugging shows that the command is beginning, but execution never completes. The ftp server to which I am trying to connect definitely does exist.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qftp.html#hasPendingCommands) for QFtp::hasPendingCommands says that

> The command that is being executed is not considered as a scheduled
>   command.

So it's normal for it to be false immediately after the call to `connectToHost()`.

For the problem of the slot connected to `commandStarted()` never been called, it's hard to say from the code shown, but a typical reason would be that your code doesn't return to Qt's main event loop. QFtp is asynchronous, so if the Qt event loop doesn't run, nothing happens.